# laravel/lumen abort continue middleware execution

Tags: laravel, exception, middleware, lumen, abort

I have a route with some custom middlewares, and a controller attached to this route.

When I get into my controller, I need to make a check on a custom object (passed in the request) to abort controller action if needed.

```
public function myControllerFunction(Request $request){
...

    if(isset($data["data-key"])){
       abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "custom abort message");
    }
...
//do other call

}
```

The abort action is launched, I see it in my log with the corresponding message BUT the middlewares continue execution and get into an other error (because of the abort in the controller, that break before calling another method).
So the initial response error message is overridden.

My objective is to stop my code running in the controller, and stop middleware execution that are set as « after ». I expected that an abort would cancel all code execution.

I tried with a `throw Exception(…)` but the result is the same, with custom exception without any success. I tried also with a "funky style" code in the middleware (where i check if there is already an error message or an exception in the request) but that's not correct to make it at this location.

Why does the abort not cancelling code execution ?

---

for more information, my router looks like this :

```
$router->post(
      'path',
       [
          'as' => 'element.functionName',
          'uses'=>'ElementResourceController@myControllerFunction',
          'middleware' => [
             'middleware-before-1',
             'middleware-before-2',
             'middleware-before-3',
             'middleware-after-1',
             'middleware-after-2',
             'middleware-after-3'
          ],
       ]
 );
```

---

my before middleware looks like this

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){

    // do things
    if(this){
        //do that
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

---

my after middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
    $resp = $next($request);
    ///do things

    //other error at this line, because abort in controller did not work as expected
    //this middleware should not be executed
    $element = Element::findOrFail($resp->getData()->key); 

    return $resp;
}
```

Comment: please try `return abort(`

Comment: i have the same issue with a `return abort(...)`